# Ajax request not updating

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I made an ajax call to a servlet and it responds with data which I can see in the page source (so that is working), but the data is not being shown on the page.

In Javascript:

```
if(date!=null && staff!=null && task!=null && project!=null )
 {
     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML="<table><c:forEach var='entry' items='${ref}' varStatus='count'> <tr><td id='column1'>${count.index+1}<td>${entry.staff}</td><td>${entry.date}</td><td>${entry.project}</td>"+
        "<td>${entry.task}</td><td>${entry.notes}</td><td>${entry.hours}</td></tr></c:forEach></table>";
        }   
      }
     xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
     xmlhttp.send();

 }
```

I have a div in my html called "myTable" so once the script is executed, I want the the table data to appear.  Sometimes the page freezes and sometimes it says there's an internal server error.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how it can be fixed? Thanks!

Comment: first of all the jstl code that you are setting in the innerHTML wont work, anyway I suggest you to put one alert to test if that piece of code is been invoked

Comment: 1) Why in the world you are not using jQuery?
2) What are you trying to attain with those JSTL tags? You know that JSTL is created in server side right? All you gonna get is a javascript function bloated with a huge string with html table code.
3) Why aren't you using jQuery?